# point in time recovery on postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

We need some help with the point in recovery test . We have followed the below steps but after creating recovery.conf file and restarting the machine our DB is getting corrupted and not getting started.
Please look at the below steps and help us analyze what is going wrong there. We have used offline postgresql installer to set up database. Required configuration like wal_level=hot_stanby, archive_mode=on, and archive_command='cp %p /mnt/server/archive/%f' in postgresql.conf are also set properly.

1. After DB set up, We have created a tablcespace, db and mapped db with the tablespace. Also created some tables to generate transaction files in pg_wal and archive directory (which is mnt/server/archive)
2. SELECT pg_start_backup('TestPITR');
3. Taken backup(tar) of Postgresql data directory (opt/PostgreSQL/10/ data)>>tar zcf backup20180810.tar data/
4. SELECT pg_stop_backup();
5. Created some more tables and noted down their timestamp (for PITR, which will be added in recovery.conf file as recovery_target_time )
6. Stopped the DB>>service postgresql-10 stop
7. Created a new directory >>mkdir pgbackup
8. Moved tar file into the pgbackup directory >>mv backup20180810.tar /opt/PostgreSQL/10/pgbackup
9. Copied archive files into the pgbackup directory>>  cp -r /mnt/server/archive/ /opt/PostgreSQL/10/pgbackup/
10. Renamed the old data directory( opt/PostgreSQL/10/ data )to bad.data >>> mv data bad.data (now opt/PostgreSQL/10/ bad.data)
11. untar the  back taken in step 2>>tar -xvf backup20180810.tar
12. Moved the data directory to old path >>>mv /opt/PostgreSQL/10/pgbackup/data/ /opt/PostgreSQL/10/ (Now i have opt/PostgreSQL/10/ data-derived from tar file and with old transaction logs in pg_wal)

13  Copied the updated pg_wal logs from bad.data to data >>>cp -r /opt/PostgreSQL/10/bad.data/pg_wal/0* /opt/PostgreSQL/10/data/pg_wal

14. Started the database  >> service postgresql-10 start (Our db works fine)
15. Created a recovery.conf file inside data folder >>opt/PostgreSQL/10/ data --given the permission and user as postgres

Our recovery.conf file has two following parameters. recovery_target_time was taken from step-5

1. restore_command = 'cp /opt/PostgreSQL/10/pgbackup/archive/%f %p'
2. recovery_target_time = '2018-08-10 02:56:31'
3. Restarted the db server>> service postgresql-10 restart

It doesn't restart also there is no log entry in log folder(opt/PostgreSQL/10/data/log) looks like it has stopped creating logs after restart.

Answer (score 1):

Steps 14 and 15 are the wrong way around. You have to create `recovery.conf` before starting the server.

Comment: We have tried that also but no luck. Everything seems to be working fine until we create recovery.conf and restart the db server.

Comment: Hi Laurenz, We managed do PITR after some fixing some permission issue on database. But there is another problem. 
>In recovery.conf file if we give recovery_target_time as  2018-09-05 09:54:21 (without EST)  and restart the psql recovery.conf is not getting changed to recovery.done. Although PITR is successful and only till given time records/tables are restored. But database goes in recovery mode and i am unable to enter more records.In the second case if i add EST and restart the postgresql, recovery.conf is getting changed to recovery.done but everything is getting restored

Comment: Perhaps you have `hot_standby = on`. Open another question for this and don't forget to include the configuration and the log file entries.

Comment: Thanks a lot Laurenz. hot_standby = on is commented out right now. Sure I will open another question with more details.

Comment: Dang. I meant `standby_mode`, not `hot_standby`.

Comment: Even this option is commented out in recovery.conf. I am using only two parameters in recovery.conf>restore_command and recovery_target_time. Shall i try with standby_mode=off once?

Comment: No, that is the default. Go ahead with a new question.